# How to read in a text file of tab-separated integers in C?

Tags: c

I have a file of simply tab-separated integers (a .txt file) and I wish to read them in with just C, line by line.  So, say each line has 5 integers.  How can I accomplish this?

My first attempt was as follows.  It was just to read in a single integer, but even that didn't work:

```
    FILE *fp;
    char blah[255];
    int *some_int;
fp = fopen("test.txt", "rt");
while (fgets(blah, 255, fp) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(blah, "%d", some_int);
    printf("%d\n", *some_int);
}
```

Comment: I'll update with my initial attempt..

Comment: `some_int` is an uninitaliazed pointer. Why did you take some_int is of type `int*` ? Any reason.

Comment: Does each line have the same number of digits? If so, is this number a compile-time constant or a run-time value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way no one else suggested, that doesn't use `fscanf` so you can have sane error handling:

```
char buffer[BUFSIZE];
size_t size = 5;
int *data = malloc(size * sizeof *line);

if(line == NULL) error();

while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp)
  {
    size_t i = 0;
    char *next = buffer;
    while(*next && *next != '\n')
      {
        data[i++] = strtol(next, &next, 0);
        // check for errors
      }
  }
```

Basically, instead of trying to use `*scanf`'s `"%d"` to read characters, use the function it (probably) calls to do the conversion: `strtol`. Where `*scanf` goes through the string to match the format string but doesn't let you "save your place" in between function calls, `strtol` does, which is what you need to read an arbitrary number of integers.

I haven't written all your code for you - you have to do the hard error handling. Possible errors include:

1. `i == size`, in which case you can try to make `data` bigger with `realloc`. Alternately, you could loop through the buffer and count how many numbers there are beforehand, then allocate that many so you don't need to reallocate later.
2. `fgets` didn't read the entire line (check that the last character before `'\0'` is `'\n'`). In this case you'll probably want to refill the buffer and keep reading numbers. Be careful in this case - you'll likely need to go back and recalculate the last number - `fgets` might have cut it off. (This is one disadvantage to using `fgets`.)
3. Erroneous input - handle however you like.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    int scanned = 0;
    int some_ints[5];
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    while ((scanned = fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d %d", some_ints, some_ints+1, some_ints+2, some_ints+3, some_ints+4)) !=  EOF) {
        if(scanned ==5){
            printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", some_ints[0], some_ints[1], some_ints[2], some_ints[3], some_ints[4]);
        }
        else {
            printf("Whoops! Input format is incorrect!\n");
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Not sure if the OP's data is in a fixed number of lines per file, but I much prefer the OP's `fgets` / `sscanf` combination for safety and error handling (though (s)he should to make it more robust) than just plain `fscanf`. Also, your code will produce erroneous results if there are too few numbers in the file (it'll reprint old numbers).

Comment: @Chris Lutz I was assuming the input was in the correct format. I edited it to check and make sure it always managed to read 5 integers in.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
int storedVals[MAX_STORED_VALS];
int bf;
int ii=0;

while (!feof(fp) && ii<MAX_STORED_VALS) {
  if (fscanf(fp," %d",&bf)) {
    storedVals[ii++]=bf;
  }
}
```

fscanf automatically does white space trimming.  So as long as there's a space in your scan string, it'll get rid of zero or more \t (tabs) and \n (newlines) to find the next integer.  Of course, this doesn't do much by way of error correction.

Comment: Just confirming, are vectors available in C?  I thought these were a c++ feature..

Comment: Oop.  Right, they're only a c++ thing.

Comment: I changed it, but now you'd either need to know how many values to expect, or you'd need to create your own vector or list-like data-structure to store values.

Comment: If there's a chance that you'd get something besides integers and whitespace, you'd just need to check for the case where feof(fp)==false, but fscanf(fp," %d",&bf) also returns zero.  That would mean that there's a non-whitespace, non-digit character under the stream pointer.  You could get rid of that by reading characters one at a time and throwing them away.